# How to use Colab with Ubuntu 16?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, libraries, google-colaboratory, cntk

I'm trying out CNTK on Google Colab, and Colab runs on Ubuntu 18.

However, CNTK requires OpenMPI 1.10.x, but this version of OpenMPI is only available on Ubuntu 16.

Is it possible to switch Colab to Ubuntu 16 to run CNTK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched around and around and seems not possible to use Google Colab with Ubuntu 16 by now (Oct 2019), it's the OS and fixed as Ubuntu 18.

My work-around is spawning a mini Ubuntu 16 docker with port-to-port binding and and let Colab connect to this mini server as local runtime server. Creating a Ubuntu 16 in docker coz my machine is also Ubuntu 18.